# The automorphism group of a finitely generated residually finite group is residually finite

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

I came across with the following theorem (in Cellular Automata and Groups):
"Let G be a finitely generated residually finite group. Then the automorphism group Aut(G) is also residually finite".

Let $a_0 \in Aut(G), a_0 \ne id_G$. Then, there exists a $g_0 \in G$ such that $a_0(g_0) \ne g_0$. Since G is residually finite, there exists a finite group F and a homomorphism $φ: G \rightarrow F$ such that $φ(a_0(g_0)) \ne φ(g_0)$.
Consider the set H to be the intersection of all $Ker(ψ)$ where $ψ \in Hom(G,F)$.
Then H is a normal subgroup of G. Observe that for every $a \in Aut(G)$ we have $a(H)= a(\cap kerψ)= \cap a(kerψ)= \cap ker(ψ \cdot a^{-1})= \cap kerψ$.

I don't get the last "=".
Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As $\psi$ runs through all elements of $Aut(G)$ so does $\psi\circ a^{-1}$.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Yes, this was more or less my answer (except that here we consider morphisms form G to F, not automorphisms of G). Do you have any idea of why it was downvoted?

Comment: @AnneBauval I guess because you wrote no words explaining it, and just repeated what was written in the question. It's a much better answer now and so has been upvoted.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven (I did a little more than repeating the question, but) thanks for your useful comments. The first one helped me to improve my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since $a\in\operatorname{Aut}(G),$ as $ψ$ runs through all elements of $\operatorname{Hom}(G,F),$ so does $ψ\circ a^{-1}.$ Hence
$$\bigcap_{\psi\in\operatorname{Hom}(G,F)}\ker(ψ\circ a^{-1})= \bigcap_{\varphi\in\operatorname{Hom}(G,F)}\ker\varphi.$$